# Apple News: News channels not available

Tags: ios, news.app

I changed Apple News channels to read the news, adding standard channels like New York Times, CNN, and The Economist.

The Economist works, but NYT and CNN present an error:

> **Channel Unavailable**
>
> This channel isn't currently available in your region.

That's weird. My settings are standard, and all over the web says that Apple News should work: the language is English, the region format is United States.

I've also tried from the **News** section: Bloomberg, The Guardian, LA Times, Reuters, WSJ, and The Washington Post. None of them works.

**Non-news channels** as Wired, National Geographic, Ars Technica, Fortune, Food52, Food Network, Smithsonian, Men's Health. Fox News, NPR, and HuffPost work, weirdly.

How can I see those channels?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Currently Italy, but the same behavior was in Greece and France.

Comment: It seems to me that Apple News is only available in North America, but changing your region to the United States should avoid that. Does loading nytimes.com in your country work?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. I am traveling in Europe and it seems to be the same error everywhere. Maybe just on my phone, not so many use News app...

Comment: My best guess is that some API required doesn't load correctly from your country. Or maybe it's a bug on your phone. Or maybe the service is blocked. It's hard to say. My recommendation is just to try another news service. How does Google News and Weather work? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-news-weather/id913753848?mt=8

Comment: It's probably because specific channels will only display in certain countries.  It's not broken because you have some channels displaying without a problem.